# ¿Qué quiere decir 'maní' en el siguiente chiste?

Tags: vocabulario, argentina

Hay un grupo de músicos cómicos en la Argentina (Les Luthiers) que hace el siguiente chiste:

> Como bien dicen en inglés: “Time is money”, “El tiempo es un maní”.

¿A qué se refieren con 'maní'? Se ve que es un doble sentido.

Busqué en un diccionario, donde encontré *cacahuate/peanut* -- ¿será?

Answer (score 4):

Exactamente eso, seguramente proviene de un video de "Les Luthiers"

Ellos no hacen ningun doble sentido, es simplemente la forma de pronunciar la palabra "Money" en español Rioplatense.

Comment: Perdón, se me olvidó mencionar el nombre del grupo.  Voy a editar la pregunta.  Entonces, maní = cacahuate en este contexto?

Comment: @aparente001 Sí, maní significa cacahuete en algunos países de habla hispana (entre ellos Argentina) y es una traducción fonética de *money*. La primera parte del sketch va de un hombre que habla sin tener idea, y el chiste del maní es un ejemplo más de su improvisación.

Comment: @Jdamian no es una traducción de Money, es un chiste porque el "no sabe" como traducir Money y lo traduce fonéticamente.
En Argentina nadie nombra Maní al dinero

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, no se trata de un doble sentido. Es, más bien, un juego de palabras que surge a partir de una especie de monólogo interior (aquí, una improvisación) que en este caso sale a la luz.

Por otro lado, los chistes tienen que provocar de forma inmediata el efecto que buscan: esa es su verdadera fuerza. Si se tienen que explicar, pierden gran parte de su sentido.

Pero como aquí se está preguntando (pidiendo una explicación) digamos que la base es la frase "El tiempo es dinero", cuyo autor es **Benjamin Franklin**, que casi iniciaba *Consejos a un joven comerciante* (*Advice to a Young Tradesman*, 1748) con esta recomendación: "Recuerda que el tiempo es dinero".

Creo que lo mejor es incluir aquí dicho monólogo. De esta forma se entenderá mejor.

---

[Transcripción de un fragmento de la escena *Encuentro en el restaurante (rapsodia gastronómica)*]

> No me acuerdo si fue antes o después... no, fue después, lo que no me acuerdo es después de qué. Bueno, y claro, lo que sigue ya, bueno no tiene sentido... ya cualquiera puede... en fin, es una... tampoco quiero seguir y seguir abundando en detalles... así que yo diría que pasáramos a presenciar la Escena del Encuentro en el Restaurante, con música compuesta por Lajos... eh... ¡una música! No, no, una música que... En fin, no perdamos más tiempo, porque como bien dicen en inglés: "Time is money": el tiempo es un maní.
> (Aplausos).
> Les agradezco mucho los aplausos, pero en realidad yo lo único que hago es repetir lo que está escrito en la... en la... claro, en este caso soy simplemente un mero... un mero... un mero.

---

En resumen: se trata de un juego de palabras, y no hay que darle más vueltas.

**Referencias**

Escena completa de *Encuentro en el restaurante (rapsodia gastronómica)*
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QLd8Bxzyh1k&t=1s&pp=2AEBkAIB
(El texto que nos ocupa, a partir de 5:13]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que es usual decir es  : "El tiempo es dinero" y se refiere a que no debes perder tiempo en cosas que no te producen ganancia.

Comment: ¡Por supuesto!  Pero aquí el tema es, precisamente que se trata de un juego de palabras que se basa en un aspecto fonético, que Les Luthiers aprovechan con un fin humorístico.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24527)